# iOS Swift AVAudioPlayer how to reset currentTime to zero when finished playing

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

My code is supposed to play a C Major scale wave file on a button press. Hitting a separate stop button will stop playback and reset the currentTime to zero.

```
@IBAction func onPlayButtonClick(sender: UIButton)
{
    play.enabled = false
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cmajor", ofType: "wav")!
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:  path)
    do
    {
        scalePlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        scalePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        scalePlayer.enableRate = true
        scalePlayer.rate = 0.75
        scalePlayer.play()
    }
    catch
    {

    }

}
```

It works as intended, but how do I set the currentTime to zero when the file is finished playing? I couldn't find anything on the developer docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a delegate:

`scalePlayer.delegate = self`

Then you implement this callback

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    //set the current time here
    scalePlayer.currentTime = 0
}
```

**Update**

Here is an example how you can implement this (based on your code):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var play: UIButton!

    private var scalePlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cmajor", ofType: "wav")!
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:  path)
        scalePlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)

        scalePlayer?.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func onPlayButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
        play.enabled = false
        scalePlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        scalePlayer?.enableRate = true
        scalePlayer?.rate = 0.75
        scalePlayer?.play()
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        scalePlayer?.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please go into more detail? I'm new to this, and I don't know where to put these lines of code and how delegates work exactly.

Comment: It compiles and then immediately crashes with this error: fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That was just a sample code :) I updated my code. But make sure you connect the outlet before running it.